# Problems with copying data to large SD card

Tags: sd-card

A few days ago I got a ThinkPad T460 and until now everything worked fine ans I'm really happy.

To extend my SSD, I bought a 256GB SD Card by Kingston ([this here](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00PH5VBFQ/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)). But when copying data there is a problem.: The SD card is recognized by the System and can also be formated (there was an error onec, but I can's remember the details, sorry!). When I start copying data, the speed is quite good initially, bus then gets very slow until the process stops with an error message. In my last try it began to get very slow at approx 476.2MB and stopped at 564MB.

I am on a german language system so I dont know what the english error message is exactly, but I try to translate:

```
Error while copying... Details: Error with merging the data: Input/Output error.
```

Afterwards the next error message appears:

```
Error while copying. Details: Error with creating the folder: The filesystem is read-only.
```

Afterwards nothing works anymore and I have to unmount the card. The folders which where written at the end can not be shown. Error message:

```
This location can not be shown. Unfortunately the whole content of ... can not by shown: Error while getting the information of file ...: Input/Outout error.
```

The card is not writeable after remounting and I have to reformat it. I have the feeling that it works a bit better when copying smaller bits of data after another.

It is interesting, that it works without problems on the MacBook of my girlfriend. There are variations in speed, but I suppose this is normal.

I tried another SD card on my ThinkPad (Kingston 2GB) and it worked fine. It would be cool if also the large card would work in this way...

Infos of the cardreader:

```
2:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: 
    Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01) 
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [17aa:5053] 
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

My System is Ubuntu 16.04.1.

Btw: I am relatively inexperienced, so if you need more information please give me detailed descriptions. ;)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you will only ever use the card on linux, try formatting it to F2FS and try your experiment again.

Comment: Wow, intersting! This made a huge difference, but unfortunately the problem remains. Now the speed is high for a much onger (nearly 1GB), but immediately an error message an error message appears:  

    "Error while copying ... Details: Error while opening while opening ...: File system is read-only".

:(

Comment: Have you tried copying the same quantity on the Macbook or on Windows?
Have you tried NTFS?
If it works with the same files and quantity on non-linux OS, try using the card on another laptop or desktop running linux, if it reproduces the same result than you may need to log a service request with Kingston.

Comment: I tried copying the same quantity on a macbook and I tried various file systems (I'm not sure if I tried NTFS though...). On the Macbook it worked fine and (appart from F2FS) there was no difference with different file systems. I will try NTFS later and I have the opportunity to try the card on another linux macine on monday. I will post my results.

Comment: Updates: When formating to NTFS it behaves the same sa with the other file systems. I bought a SD Card reader (with official Linux support) and everything works fine with it. It would have been nice to get it to work on the internal reader, but it's also "ok" this way. I think I will use the external one to transfere data and then use the SD internally as read-only...

Comment: So looks like the culprit is the hardware itself. 
If you'll be using the external reader, perhaps switch back to F2FS as it is the best for flash storage.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! Do you think this could be something driver related which can be solved in future kernel versions?

Comment: Possibly, you will have to check with Lenovo.  Does it work on the same laptop but under Windows (if you dual boot you could try)?

Comment: No, I don't have Windows...  Well, I think I will just wait ans try again when I have a newer kernel version. I think it's ok for me with the external reader for now. Thank you again!